# Calling a function based upon ipaddress in Linux Bash Script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk, sed

I have a test.csv file which looks as below

```
LOC,IP,D1,D2
abc1,10.11|10.12|10.13|10.14|10.15|10.16,10.11.1.1,11.1.1.23
abc2,12.1|10.15|10.116|10.127|10.110,11.110.8.25,11.11.5.3
abc3,13.2|13.2,10.1.4.50,10.2.7.3
```

I want to calculate Ipaddress on the target server and then check if the `ipaddress` matches the value in `test.csv` file. If it matches then I want to call `check_func` and `pass values of D1 and D2` to that function.

So far, I am able to calculate `ipaddress` using the following command

```
host=`uname -n'`
ip_addr=`host $host | awk '{print $NF}'`
```

Now, I want to do something like below:

```
case $ip_addr in
      10.11|10.12|10.13|10.14|10.15|10.16)
             check_func "10.11.1.1" "11.1.1.23"
```

Comment: To find IP use `ip addr show`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In bash, you can use patterns stored in variables under the `extglob` shell option:

```
shopt -s extglob
case "$ip_addr" in
    @($column2)) check_func "$column3" "$column4" ;;
    *) echo Unknown. ;;
esac
```

To populate the columns, just use `read` with Internal Field Separator set to `,`:

```
#! /bin/bash
shopt -s extglob
IFS_backup=$IFS
IFS=,
while read -r column1 column2 column3 column4 ; do
    ...
done < file.csv
```

Comment: thanks. does it makes sense to combine both the scripts into one?

Comment: Exactly, replace the ellipsis in the second one with the `case` .

Comment: in that case `shopt -s extglob` will be at 2 places. Is that okay?

Comment: @meallhour: No, keep just the one in the outer scope.